# Converting to polynomial form

Tags: functions, polynomials

Is it true that if we have an equation of the form $g(a)=0$ ( $g:R→R$) then it is possible, with certain manipulations, to convert this equation into the form $P(a)=0$, where P is a polynomial?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if given $g\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, then $$(\forall a\in \Bbb R)\left(g(a)=0\overset{\Leftarrow\text{ too?}}{\Longrightarrow} \text{There exists a polynomial } P \text{ such that } P(a)=0\right)?$$

Answer (score 1):

No.  Take $g(x)=\sin x$; although this has many zeroes, it is not a polynomial.